# GitHub diff: count characters instead of lines

Tags: git, github, metrics, code-metrics

I ran a search and didn't come up with anything; so, decided to see what the community has to offer on this score.

When you commit to GitHub it performs a diff. The diff tells you how many *lines* were added and how many *lines* were removed.

From a metrics perspective, this doesn't impress me much considering a lot of the languages I use aren't dependent on whitespace characters to function. Therefore, an entire class with 50 methods can be defined in a single line (not that you would do that, of course).

Measuring lines can lead us to believe that single-line solutions are inherently better than the alternative.

So, I'm curious if there's a way to have GitHub (or Git in general) display the difference in non-whitespace character count.

Example:

```
class Something
{
    function hello()
    {
    }
}
```

Changed to:

```
class Something {
    function hello() {
    }
}
```

Would result in something like this:

Line change: -2 Character change: 0

Answer (score 0):

To Find Line Change use below Command (Subtract 1 from final result shown)

```bash
git diff abc.txt | grep  "+" |grep -c -v "@@"
```

Output: 3

```
git diff abc.txt
```

Output:

```
diff --git a/abc.txt b/abc.txt
index 9ab6740..c2ab3e3 100644
--- a/abc.txt
+++ b/abc.txt
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
 my
-qq
+qq1
 wq
 my
 q
@@ -8,7 +8,7 @@ q
 q
 q
 q
-q
+q1
 q
 q
```

Comment: I don't want to downvote this, but I don't think the desired outcome was achieved. Line count is not the issue. Character count is the issue. I don't see in this answer where the character count is displayed and what change there was. Am I missing it?

Comment: Sure , but i tried this and i dont think there is a direct way for second part of your question, only way if you write some custom program which identifies this

Answer (score 0):

I had kind of the same problem and tried to solve it using the `--word-diff` parameter for `git diff`.

tl;dr

`echo $(git diff --cached --word-diff --color | grep -oP '\x1b\[[0-9;]*m\{\+([^\x1b]*)\+\}\x1b' | cut -d+ -f 2- | rev | cut -d+ -f 2- | tr -d '\n' | wc -c) - $(git diff --cached --word-diff --color | grep -oP '\x1b\[[0-9;]*m\[\-([^\x1b]*)\-\]\x1b' | cut -d- -f 2- | rev | cut -d- -f 2- | tr -d '\n' | wc -c) | bc`

---

Some explanation:

- `git diff --cached --word-diff --color`
  Prints the word diff of the currently staged against the HEAD.
- `grep -oP '\x1b\[[0-9;]*m\{\+([^\x1b]*)\+\}\x1b'`
  Filters for all added content (also if the colors are changed in git config).
- `cut -d+ -f 2- | rev | cut -d+ -f 2-`
  Complicated version of filtering the content between the surrounding `{+` and `+}`, I couldn't come up with a reliable alternative version.
- `tr -d '\n' | wc -c`
  Counts the characters without newlines.

The second part is actually quite the same but with matching `[-` and `-]` instead of `{+` and `+}` for the deleted content.
After all `echo` joins the two numbers with a `-` such that `bc` can calculate the difference.

One additional comment: I opted for colorized output, since this makes pattern matching much easier (in cases where you added characters that are used to match start or end, like `+}`, `[-`, ...)

Here is basically the same logic written in Python:

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import re

process = Popen(["git", "diff", "--cached", "--word-diff", "--color"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()

if stderr:
  print(stderr.decode())
  exit(1)

stdout = stdout.decode()
added = re.findall(r"\x1b\[[0-9;]*m\{\+([^\x1b]*)\+\}\x1b", stdout)
deleted = re.findall(r"\x1b\[[0-9;]*m\[-([^\x1b]*)-\]\x1b", stdout)
num_added = sum(len(a) for a in added)
num_deleted = sum(len(d) for d in deleted)
print(num_added - num_deleted)
```

Save it in a file and call it from within the git repository.